# Who hired the Churchmice to steal the Shroud of Turin?

Tags: the-dresden-files

In *Skin Game* (chapter 9) Harry tells Ascher that Nicodemus once hired the Churchmice to steal the Shroud of Turin (back in *Death Masks*).  Anna Valmont later appears to confirm this.

By my recollection, though, in *Death Masks* it was clear that it was

> Marcone.

Is this a continuity error, or perhaps a retcon, or did I miss something in *Death Masks*?  Nicodemus did catch up with the thieves suspiciously quickly (Gaston was killed the morning after the theft) which suggests he knew about it in advance, but I don't recall that we ever knew how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has been confirmed to be a continuity error. Death Masks is the correct version of events, and Skin Games is the incorrect version. Marcone hired the Churchmice. Priscilla Spencer, who works with Jim Butcher in multiple roles, confirmed it was a mistake on Reddit.

http://www.reddit.com/r/dresdenfiles/comments/26q2v2/skin_game_spoilers_inconsistencies_that_arent/chtr74w

Additionally, since you have read Skin Game, you know that Nicodemus has a very useful means of gathering intelligence that would make it easy for him to notice something like the Shroud theft. If you don't recall, reread Kringle and Dresden's conversation.